# Notification with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter-3

I have notification system in CodeIgniter and I have created a view page when I put my result from Notification class, so I need help because I don't have any result.

This is my my view **nombre.php:**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) exit;
include ("notif_model.php");

$notification = new notif_model();

$notifications = $notification->getcountNotif();
echo $notifications;


?>
```

And this is my class **notif_model.php:**

```
class notif_model extends CI_Model
{

    var $type;//reservation request, comment, message
    var $to_user;
    var $from_user;
    var $reference;//comm id, message id
    var $timestamp;
    var $newcount;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    function insertNotification($notification)
    {
        $this->db->insert('notification',$notification);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    function countNotif()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('to_user',$this->session->userdata('id'));
        $this->db->where('seen',0);
        $query = $this->db->get('notification');
        $res = $query->num_rows();
        return $res;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: The function name is `countNotif()` not `getcountNotif()` like this `$notification->countNotif();`

Comment: yes i do it but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

```
function countNotif()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('to_user',$this->session->userdata('id'));
    $this->db->where('seen',0);
    $query = $this->db->get('notification');
    $res = $query->num_rows();

    echo $this->db->last_query(); exit; // will print the query string

    return $res;
}
```

run and check the query ....

Comment: i do it and i put in autoload file :$autoload['model'] = array('notif_model'); and i don't know why she doesn't work